# Sending data to windows in Chrome apps

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-app

I successfully created windows in a Chrome app.

```
chrome.app.window.create("register.html", {
 width: 500, height: 400, frame: "chrome"
}, function(appWindow) {} )
```

How can I send data to a specific window if I have created many windows? I want to achieve a chat like feature. I have distinguished user name by using that. I want to create a window if the user is new. If a window is created already for the user I want to send a message to that window.

Comment: If you are making an app then `google-chrome-extension` is the wrong tag,  change to `google-chrome-app` if this is the case. As for your question, what's wrong with using [messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/messaging) via the background page?